# R bookdown document with theorem does not render when output_file is specified

Tags: r, latex, bookdown

I have a `bookdown` document that contains a theorem chunk.  The yaml configuration is

```
title: "Test document"
toc: no # table of contents - these are manually defined below so they are put in the right place
lof: no # list of figures
lot: no # list of tables
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    keep_tex: yes 
rmd_files: ["test.Rmd"]
documentclass: article
classoption: a4paper
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
geometry:
  [left=3.17cm,
   right=1.75cm,
   top=2.95cm,
   bottom=5cm]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: true
```

and the body is

````
# The discrete convolution formula 

We present a formula for the distribution of the sum of two random variables in Theorem \@ref(thm:discConvForm).

```{theorem, discConvForm, name = "Discrete convolution formula", echo = TRUE}
Consider two independent discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ with probability mass functions $f_X$ and $f_Y$ respectively. Let us also assume that $X$ and $Y$ take values from the set of non-negative integers. Then, the random variable $Z = X + Y$ has probability mass function $f_Z$ given by
$$f_Z(z) = f_{X+Y}(z) = P(Z = z) = \sum_{t = 0}^z f_X(t)f_Y(z - t)$$
```
````

When I run `bookdown::render_book("test.Rmd", output_dir = "output")`, it renders fine. When I run `bookdown::render_book("test.Rmd", output_dir = "output", output_file = "newTest.pdf")`, it gives the following error:

```
/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS _main.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output newTest.tex --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --template /Users/alex/Library/R/3.4/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --number-sections --highlight-style tango --latex-engine /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable tables=yes --standalone 
/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS _main.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output newTest.pdf --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --template /Users/alex/Library/R/3.4/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --number-sections --highlight-style tango --latex-engine /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable tables=yes --standalone 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.94 \BeginKnitrBlock

pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

I have investigated the `.tex` files produced. When  I run `render_book` without `output_file` specified, there is a block of LaTeX code just before `\begin{document}` which specifies `\BeginKnitrBlock` (see below). However, when I run `render_book` with `output_file` specified, that block does not exist.

The block in question:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\let\BeginKnitrBlock\begin \let\EndKnitrBlock\end
```

How can I fix this? I would like to be able to specify the output file name.

---

`SessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bookdown_0.5.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13    digest_0.6.12   withr_1.0.2     rprojroot_1.2   R6_2.2.2        backports_1.1.1 magrittr_1.5    git2r_0.18.0    evaluate_0.10.1 httr_1.3.1     
[11] stringi_1.1.5   curl_2.8.1      rstudioapi_0.6  rmarkdown_1.6   devtools_1.12.0 tools_3.4.2     stringr_1.2.0   yaml_2.1.14     compiler_3.4.2  memoise_1.1.0  
[21] htmltools_0.3.6 knitr_1.17
```

Comment: I don't have time to investigate this issue, but usually I don't recommend you to use `output_file`: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/808#issuecomment-339424655

Comment: @YihuiXie I am testing the 19 templates in R bookdownplus package. I have just found  that *the block in question* mentioned in this question is inserted automatically when using some templates, but not inserted when using others. I don't know why. This block conflicts with a new template which i am working on, because some command is already defined in the template. The only trick I know is from this question: use 'output_file' to avoid inserting the block. It works, but it is weird. I was wondering if  there is a better way to control it.